# Missing $ error and undefined control sequence, while all seems correct

Tags: math-mode

I've written this code

```
\subsection*{Definitie 1}
\textit{Als $z$, $f(z)$ \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, dan is de M-de Frechet afgeleide van $f$, voorgesteld
door $f$^{(M)}$(z)$ een operator op \mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{R}^{m} (M maal)
, die lineair is in elk van de operandi met als waarde}
```

But I can't compile the document, as I get a "$ missing" and "Undefined control sequence" error. I've already checked this code a dozen times, but can't seem to find anything wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome-to-tex-sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Have a look at the `Not so short guide to LaTeX`, and in your first few documents, always build up your code slowly, compiling frequently- this will help you find where the errors are :)

Comment: @cmhughes very appropriate advise. Do you mind if I rephrase it (well copy it almost verbatim) into my answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sure, go for it :)

Answer (score 5):

You had several math mode expressions written in text mode; I've fixed them in the code below. I would suggest you to use the [`amsthm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) package to define a theorem-like structure with the desired formatting for your definitions; in this way, the formatting and numbering are dona automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mydefi}
  {\topskip}{\topskip}
  {\itshape}{}
  {\bfseries}{}
  {\newline}{}
\theoremstyle{mydefi}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definitie}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Als $z$, $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, dan is de $M$-de Fr\'echet afgeleide van $f$, voorgesteld door $f^{(M)}(z)$ een operator op $\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ ($M$ maal), die lineair is in elk van de operandi met als waarde
\end{defi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `Fr\'echet`; but loading `inputenc` with the appropriate encoding, you can simply write `Fréchet`.

By the way, for definitions it's also common to use use the roman (upright) font instead of italics;  in this case, you can change the definition of the `mydefi` style to:

```
\newtheoremstyle{mydefi}
  {\topskip}{\topskip}
  {}{}
  {\bfseries}{}
  {\newline}{}
```

I would also like to suggest you (quoting **cmhughes**'s valuable comment) to have a look at some introductory material (the [`Not so short guide to LaTeX`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort/) (available in seveal languages) and the [`amsmath package documentation`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf), for example); in your first few documents, always build up your code slowly, compiling frequently- this will help you find where the errors are.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 100K `:-)`

Comment: May I suggest (again) to change `Frechet` to `Fr\'echet` (or `Fréchet` + proper `inputenc`) and `\ldots` to `\dotsb`? And congratulations on the 100k!

Comment: @kahen of course, will do the changes right now; thanks for pointing them out. And thanks for your kind words!

Answer (score 3):

You have few misplaced and missing `$`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Definitie 1}
\textit{Als $z$, $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, dan is de M-de Frechet afgeleide van $f$, voorgesteld
door $f^{(M)}(z)$ een operator op $\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{R}^{m} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ (M maal)
, die lineair is in elk van de operandi met als waarde}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that only characters were to be placed between the $'s. And I was using the wrong math package. (I'm just learning :s )

Comment: Further problems are: (1) missing `$..$` pairs around "M", (2) Fréchet's name is misspelled, (3) `\ldots` in the product should be `\dotsb` and (4) this would probably be better implemented using `amsthm`, `ntheorem` or `thmtools`.

Comment: @kahen: I don't understand anything written in there `;-)`. Is it german? Only goal is to eliminate errors. `:-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar it's Dutch probably.